# Vue component access data object

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How can i check if an object have a children element inside computed properties
EX. https://jsfiddle.net/zvku6voo/

I need to check submenu function on click, on load page and pass default open submenu, How can i access the current object on submenu function?

HTML and template:

```
<template id="ids-sidebar-menu-template">
    <li v-for="li in list" >
        <a href="@{{ li.url }}" @click="toggle" >
            @{{li.title}}
            <span v-if="submenu" class="right"> + </span>
        </a>
        <ul v-show="open" v-if="submenu">
            <ids-sidebar-menu :list="li.children"></ids-sidebar-menu>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Vue Component:

```
Vue.component('ids-sidebar-menu', {
    template : '#ids-sidebar-menu-template',
    props: {
        list : Array
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            open: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        submenu: function () {
                return true;
                // problem here
            return this.children && this.children.length
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.submenu)
                this.open = !this.open
        }
    }
});
```

Data:

```
var data = [
    {
        title : 'Title 1',
        url : '#',
        children: [
            {
                title : 'Subtitle 1',
                url : '#'
            },
            {
                title : 'Subtitle 2',
                url : '#'
            },
            {
                title : 'Subtitle 3',
                url : '#'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title : 'Title 2',
        url : '#'
    }
];
```

Vue:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el : '#sidebar-menu',
    data: {
        links: data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are passing the whole list to each of the `<ids-submenu-item>` components. Each submenu item component should only be passed the items it needs to display, not all of the links.  Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvku6voo/2/

```
<ul id="sidebar-menu">
    <ids-sidebar-menu v-for="item in links" :line="item"></ids-sidebar-menu>
</ul>

<template id="ids-sidebar-menu-template">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ line.url }}" @click="toggle" >
            {{line.title}}
            <span v-if="submenu" class="right"> + </span>
        </a>
        <ul v-show="open" v-if="submenu">
            <ids-sidebar-menu v-for="item in line.children" :line="item"></ids-sidebar-menu>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

js:

```
props: {
        line : Object
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            open: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        submenu: function () {
            return this.line.children && this.line.children.length
        }
    },
```

Comment: how can i add a default active item or submenu item and open on load?